# Does C# Stopwatch pause when my computer goes to sleep?

Tags: c#, sleep, stopwatch

I'm measuring the runtime of my program (written in C#) with Stopwatch. My computer went sleep, and I don't know that the time data it shows is correct or not. So is `Stopwatch` measuring the sleep time too or it was paused then continued?

Comment: Run a test.  Try it and find out.

Comment: Why don't you just try it under controlled conditions?

Comment: `Stopwatch` calls a method `GetTimestamp()` when it is started and when it is stopped. Then it just subtracts the two timestamps.

Comment: @Joe The running takes hours, I don't want to start it again if not necessary, thats why I'm asking here.

Comment: It's hard to think that stopwatch starts a separate thread that "count" time... As other users suggested it just take Timestamp when it starts and stop

Comment: Just don't let the computer go to sleep?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [source code for `StopWatch`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,f56fda03f3c59486) the method `Start` looks like this:

```
public void Start() {
    // Calling start on a running Stopwatch is a no-op.
    if(!isRunning) {
        startTimeStamp = GetTimestamp();                 
        isRunning = true;
    }
}
```

The method `Stop` looks like this:

```
public void Stop() {
    // Calling stop on a stopped Stopwatch is a no-op.
    if( isRunning) {
        long endTimeStamp = GetTimestamp();                 
        long elapsedThisPeriod = endTimeStamp - startTimeStamp;
        elapsed += elapsedThisPeriod;
        isRunning = false;

        if (elapsed < 0) {
            // When measuring small time periods the StopWatch.Elapsed* 
            // properties can return negative values.  This is due to 
            // bugs in the basic input/output system (BIOS) or the hardware
            // abstraction layer (HAL) on machines with variable-speed CPUs
            // (e.g. Intel SpeedStep).

            elapsed = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**So the answer of your question is:** It measures the duration by using two timestamps which leads to the conclusion that it doesn't matter whether your computer goes to sleep or not.

**Update** (thanks Mike and Joe):
However, if your computer is sleeping, it cannot run your program - so the measured duration would be the sum of the duration the program has been running and the duration where the computer has been sleeping.
`TotalDuration = CalculationDuration + SleepDuration`.

Comment: It would matter since the test wasn't running while the computer was sleeping, since the stopwatch will account for all of that time. If the stopwatch said it took 12 hours to complete, and the computer slept for 4 hours, then the test actually only took 8 hours.

Comment: @mike...  I'm confused about what you're saying.  I think you need to re-think your comment.

Comment: @Joe, I was thinking from the OP's standpoint. No, the computer going to sleep won't affect the `StopWatch` elapsed time, but it would affect the test results. The `StopWatch` would be an indication of total time elapsed even when the PC was sleeping, while in actuality, the test never ran the whole time. Therefore, the `Stopwatch` time would not correlate with the amount of time the test took.

Comment: @mike... oh, got it.  Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Updated the answer ;-)

Answer (score 10):

The stopwatch does not pause when the computer enters sleep.

It uses the Windows API [`QueryPerformanceCounter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which [does not reset the count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when the computer goes to sleep:

> "QueryPerformanceCounter reads the performance counter and returns the
>   total number of ticks that have occurred since the Windows operating
>   system was started, including the time when the machine was in a sleep
>   state such as standby, hibernate, or connected standby."

Comment: Dear downvoter: Care to explain what's wrong with this answer? As far as I know, it's factually correct, so it would be most illuminating to discover what is wrong with it.

Comment: Also don't understand the downvote. This answer was way more helpful to me than the accepted one. +1 to balance the BS.